# Stop auto scroll in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a changing number of cells, Which means some cells will remain unseen by the user unless he scrolls down to see them.

But once this happens, the scroll view is auto scrolling up once again, Leaving the unseen cells untouchable (not possible to select them while scrolling).

I have tried:

```
_alarmListScroll.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

Which does nothing apparently, and:

```
_alarmListScroll.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

Which stops the scrolling completely.

How should this be done?

Comment: Did you write any reloading mechanism when user scrolls to the bottom list ?

Comment: What do you mean by reloading mechanism? didn't think i had to implement such thing

Comment: Are you calling [tableview reloadData] from anywhere in your code ?

Comment: No, but why should i reload the data? all is there and the cells are visible once dragged down. should i really call this?

Comment: I'm not asking you to call that method, instead asking whether you actually wrote it or not, usually this kind of issues arise due to calling reloadData method from incorrect place (like cellForRowAtIndexPath).

Comment: Well, No, it does not appear in the code...

Comment: your tableview is showing first cell or row automatically after scrolling down?

Comment: I drag the tableview down, and then it automatically bounces back up, so basically yes

Comment: Your problem looks like an content inset problem. Have your properly set up your content insets corresponding to any available (overlapping) navigation or toolbars bars?